# how to start a MapActvity from Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, mapactivity

i'm trying to start a map activity from a normal Activity.
But keep getting the error:

```
10-20 10:47:08.828: ERROR/dalvikvm(1102): Could not find class 'com.xxApp.MapAnalyseActivity', referenced from method com.xxApp.xxAppActivity$1.run
10-20 10:47:11.578: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1102): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.xxApp.MapAnalyseActivity
```

when i try to do:

```
startActivity(new Intent(xxAppActivity.this, MapAnalyseActivity.class));
xxAppActivity.this.finish();
```

Here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.xxApp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".xxAppActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/xxTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity android:label="@string/mapAnalyse" android:name="MapAnalyseActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@style/xxTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xxApp.MapAnalyseActivity" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your manifest.xml should look like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.xxApp"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".xxAppActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/xxTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:label="@string/mapAnalyse" android:name="MapAnalyseActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:theme="@style/xxTheme"/>

         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>              
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that MapActivity is in the **Same Folder ?**

or try giving full path in manifest as

```
com.packagename.mapactivity
```